# Get value of attribute with invoke()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I'm trying to get the value of an attribute and do stuff with it. I read the documentation and I think I'm following quite strictly what it says, and it's something quite simple I want to achieve.

I have an HTML element like this: `<span class="mySpan" data-test-count="8" />` and I want to read the value of `data-test-count`, so I go like:

```
cy.get('.mySpan').invoke('attr', 'data-test-count').then((count) => cy.log(count))
```

It logs nothing, but seems to me to be the same approach I found on the docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Notes).

```
cy.get('input')
  .invoke('getKendoDropDownList')
  .then((dropDownList) => {
    // yields the return of $input.getKendoDropDownList()
    return dropDownList.select('apples')
  })
```

The curious thing is that I am in fact able to get the value of that attribute, this runs smoothly:

```
cy.get('.mySpan').invoke('data-test-count').should('equal', '8') // this passes :O
```

### Update:

It seems that the problem only occurs for elements that are created by mapping an array. Showing some more detailed code below:

This is my component (it's React)

```
<Container>
      <span className="mySpan" data-test-count="8">
        ciao
      </span>
      {counts.map((count) => (
        <Info
          className={`counter-${count.name}`}
          key={count.name}
          data-test={`counter-${count.name}`}
          data-test-count={count.count}
        >
          {`${t(`${modelName}.${count.name}`)} (${count.count ?? 0})`}
        </Info>
      ))}
    </Container>
```

This logs nothing (trying to get the value of one of the `Info`s) BUT the element is visible and the `.should('be.visible')` passes.

```
cy.get('.counter-active')
      .should('be.visible')
      .invoke('attr', 'data-test-count')
      .then((count) => cy.log(count))
```

This logs `8`:

```
cy.get('.mySpan')
      .should('be.visible')
      .invoke('attr', 'data-test-count')
      .then((count) => cy.log(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "attr" to invoke:

```
cy.get('.mySpan').invoke('attr', 'data-test-count').then((count) => cy.log(count));
```